# CANNON.js custom rigid body

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I'm tinkering a bit with cannon.js and three.js, and i wish to have terrain. This would require a custom `CANNON.RigidBody`. I've seen the predefined shapes, like plane, box and sphere, but i cannot seem to figure out where or how cannon defines its shapes. is there a way to create a `CANNON.RigidBody` from a `THREE.Geometry`, or `THREE.Mesh` or even define it poly, by poly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to construct a terrain, you could use the [CANNON.Heightfield](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Heightfield.html) class. [See the example](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/heightfield.html).

There's currently no way to feed an arbitrary polygon/trimesh directly into Cannon.js. More on the subject [here](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/issues/43).

UPDATE: The new [CANNON.Trimesh class](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/master/src/shapes/Trimesh.js) can be used for trimesh collisions. It is currently limited to sphere and plane collisions.